# Mockito versions behaving differently on a test case

Tags: java, mockito

I have fairly simple Test case below which is passing when I use the Mockito 1.19 version but failing when I switched to Mockito 3.x.

```
@Test(expected = DBMapperRetryableException.class)
public void testUpdateInventoryWithException() throws DBMapperRetryableException, DBMapperNonRetryableException {
    when(baseDBOperations.partialUpdate(anyString(), any(PrimaryKey.class), anyString(), anyString(), any(ReturnValue.class), any(ValueMap.class))).thenThrow(new DBMapperRetryableException("Exception", new Throwable()));

    assertNull(prebookInventoryDao.updateInventory(PrebookInventoryUpdateInfo.builder().hashKey(DUMMY).sortKey(123).incrementValue(1).build()));
    // verify(baseDBOperations, times(1)).partialUpdate(anyString(), any(PrimaryKey.class), anyString(), anyString(), any(ReturnValue.class), any(ValueMap.class));
}
```

Above shows the below message when I run it on Intellij:

```
[MockitoHint] PrebookInventoryDaoTest.testUpdateInventoryWithException (see javadoc for MockitoHint):
[MockitoHint] 1. Unused... -> at com.amazon.pbxcoreservice.dao.PrebookInventoryDaoTest.testUpdateInventoryWithException(PrebookInventoryDaoTest.java:68)
[MockitoHint]  ...args ok? -> at com.amazon.pbxcoreservice.dao.PrebookInventoryDao.updateInventory(PrebookInventoryDao.java:51)
```

Error shown: `java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: com.amazon.pbxcoreservice.dynamodb.exception.DBMapperRetryableException`

Here's the PrebookInventoryDao class. I've skipped a few methods like getUpdateExpression, getPrimaryKey.

```
public class PrebookInventoryDao {

private final BaseDBOperations baseDBOperations;

public PrebookInventoryDao(final BaseDBOperations baseDBOperations) {
    this.baseDBOperations = baseDBOperations;
}

public UpdateItemOutcome updateInventory(PrebookInventoryUpdateInfo prebookInventoryUpdateInfo)
        throws DBMapperRetryableException, DBMapperNonRetryableException {

    ConditionalExpressionRequest conditionalExpressionRequest = prebookInventoryUpdateInfo.getConditionalExpressionRequest();
    String conditionalExpression = conditionalExpressionRequest != null ? conditionalExpressionRequest.getQuery() : null;

    return baseDBOperations.partialUpdate(DynamoDBConstants.PREBOOK_INVENTORY.TABLE,
            getPrimaryKey(prebookInventoryUpdateInfo), getUpdateExpression(),
            conditionalExpression, ReturnValue.UPDATED_NEW, getValueMap(prebookInventoryUpdateInfo, conditionalExpressionRequest));
}
```

Could anyone help as to why such discrepancy?

PS: Looks like when I use `when(baseDBOperations.partialUpdate(any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any())).thenThrow(new DBMapperRetryableException("Exception", new Throwable()));`
, then the test passes. Not sure why `when(baseDBOperations.partialUpdate(anyString(), any(PrimaryKey.class), anyString(), anyString(), any(ReturnValue.class), any(ValueMap.class))).thenThrow(new DBMapperRetryableException("Exception", new Throwable()));` isn't working.